# Was Trinity (The Matrix) based on Molly (Neuromancer)?

Tags: the-matrix, inspiration, character-similarity, neuromancer

I just started reading *Neuromancer*, and found Molly being very much like Trinity from the *Matrix*: similar clothing, proficiency in combat, sometimes cold attitude, even the black sunglasses/lenses.

Have the Wachowski siblings been inspired by Molly? They sure have been inspired by *Neuromancer* in general, but I'm looking for actual production info (interviews, etc).

Have the Wachowskis ever credited the *Neuromancer*?

Comment: I can't believe I never noticed the similarities before. Also, I'm jealous that you are reading *Neuromancer* for the first time, I don't remember how surprising and amazing it must have been the first time for me. Definitely a classic. I feel like aspects of Molly may have permeated the culture enough that the Wachowskis might have been influenced by characters influenced by characters influenced by Molly.

Comment: Hmm... my first thought at reading the title of this question was, "other than being competent women in cyberpunk, they're nothing alike", but... well... hmm...  I like thought-provoking questions.

Comment: The Wachowskis definitely read Neuromancer. Whether Trinity was directly influenced is a very different matter. Apparently their goal was to make a sexy woman with a noir feel but that wasn't the villain.

Comment: You may note that Gibson doesn't begrudge them the use of his situations since he himself lifted those from earlier authors; http://www.williamgibsonbooks.com/archive/2003_01_28_archive.asp#90244012

Comment: This part made me laugh: `THE MATRIX is arguably the ultimate “cyberpunk” artifact. Or will be, if the sequels don’t blow. I hope they don’t, and somehow have a hunch they won’t, but I’m glad I’m not the one who has to worry about it.`